# how do I program my hashtag pyramid to the left?

Tags: c, cs50

I've just started a course on edx, which I'm pretty sure you all have heard of CS50 introduction to computer science from havard. I'm having a problem on my first pset, where they asked me to create a hashtag pyramid. I managed to create the pyramid but it's on the wrong side, it supposed to be like this:

```
       #
      ##
     ###
    ####
   #####
  ######
########
```

but mine is on the right... I can't find the way to flip it :(.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    //declare variables.
    int line, space, hash, user;

    //promping user until get the right answer.
    do
     {
        printf("Height of pyramid: ");
        user = GetInt();
    }
    while(user < 0 || user > 23);


    //whill print new lines
    for (line = 1; line <= user; line++)
    {
        //print spaces
        for(space = 0; space > 0; space--) {
            printf(" ");
        }

        //print hashes
        for (hash = 0; hash <= line; hash++) {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
     }
    }
```

Can anyone please help me with this? I am so frustrated right now. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the loop printing spaces. Will that ever be executed?

Comment: There are lots of questions about this CS50 exercise.  Please look at them for inspiration.  I suggest a search term '[cs50] mario' (it returns a list of 15 or so entries at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
//print spaces
for(space = 0; space > 0; space--) {
    printf(" ");
}
```

use

```
//print spaces
for(space = user - line; space > 0; space--) {
    printf(" ");
}
```

> and - (**Weather Vane** found this error - output gives 1 extra `#` in every line)

instead of

```
for (hash = 0; hash <= line; hash++) {
```

use

```
for (hash = 0; hash < line; hash++) {
```

Comment: Note the `hash` loop is slightly wrong too - it prints one hash too many. (I assume the extra hash in the last line of the example is a typo.)

Comment: Thank you - I edited my answer by adding solution to this error, too.